# How to destroy the current image in image upload

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, pdo

I want to do is when a user decided to change his profile picture the link in the database  will be update and move the image to upload folder and destroy the current link and image on the upload folder on that specific user.

My problem in my code is when a user change his profile picture it will add another picture on the upload folder. I want to do is to delete the current image first on that specific user before the new image he selected is move on the upload folder.

php code

```
<?php
include_once('../dbc/database.php');

$db = new Connection();
$db = $db->dbConnect();
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imageInput']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['imageInput']['name']);
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['imageInput']['tmp_name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageInput"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/" . $_FILES["imageInput"]["name"]);
$location = "elogFiles/upload/" . $_FILES["imageInput"]["name"];


$qOldpic = "SELECT user_image FROM tbl_user WHERE user_email = : email";
$queryOldpic = $db->prepare($qOldpic);
$queryOldpic->bindParam(':email', $email);
$queryOldpic->execute();
$num_rows = $queryOldpic->rowCount(); 


if ($num_rows == 1) {
    unlink($queryOldpic);
    $q = "UPDATE tbl_user SET user_image = '$location' WHERE user_email= :email ";
    $query = $db->prepare($q);
    $query->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $results = $query->execute();
    echo "1";
}


?>
```

Comment: Never store such images under the client provided name! Always create an internal name based on the user id to be safe. Then all you have to do is call `unlink()` on the target path before doing your `move_uploaded_file()`.

Comment: You can delete files using the function unlink().

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

above url will help you understand proper approach to delete the previous image file.

If you want to make the error message invisible when that file is not exist on given location, use '@' so you could simply ignore the error display as the following:

```
<?php
unlink($filename);
?>
```

Comment: i tried the unlink but still the image file  is still theier when i upload an another image.

Comment: I assume the $_POST['imageLink'] is pointing the current picture(to be  deleted).
You'll need to print it out whether it properly contain the full path of the file, and check the return value of unlink's call.

On top of that, I think you would better to recall $_POST['imageLink']'s value from DB directly to avoid user's exploitation in web form. (Otherwise, you should sanitize the $_POST['imageLink'] to make sure the program code is safe)

Comment: i edited my code and now it wont update also can you help me find whats wrong on it?

Answer (score 0):

Before you do your `update`, run a `select` and get the `user_image` by `email`, store it into a variable, like `$oldPicture`.

After that, you should remove the picture like this:

```
if ((!!$oldPicture) && (file_exists($oldPicture))) {
    unlink($oldPicture);
}
```

You only delete an image if you have a value for its path and the file exists. Make sure the path of `$oldPicture` is correct. Finally, after the if above you can run your `update` command. I will not delve into security problems, as it is out of scope in this question, but make sure you prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: i tried ur advise and edit my posted code..can you have a look whats wrong with it?

Comment: I do not have your database, so if you describe what you experience in your tests I can give you more help. As things are standing, you are only doing an update if a user has a previous profile picture, which is of course, not correct. My answer suggested that you should execute your update after the if, not inside. You need to be able to save a profile picture even if you have no value for it in the database or the file does not exist.

Comment: i edited my code again but still have no luck :( i've post my new code again.

Comment: As I have asked you in my previous comment I will ask again: Can you describe what you experience? I have no access to your database, therefore I cannot test your code, so your repeated action of only updating your code is less than enough. "Not working" and "No luck" does not describe your problem. And as in my previous comment, I have to point out again that your edited code still executes an update if and only if the user already has a picture stored and it exists on the specified location. You need to do your update AFTER the if, not inside it.